# How to set cups to use all paper trays on a printer?

Tags: linux, rhel, printing, cups

Our sales application runs on Linux. We have our printers set up in CUPS using the supplied Xerox Global Print Driver.

In each printer settings it has a drop down for what paper tray to use, but you can only select one. So on our printers that have 8 or so paper trays, once the one that's selected is run out, the printer stops (only when printing via Linux, Windows just uses another paper tray).

Is there any way that I can set it so that it uses all paper trays, or at least a couple?

Answer (score 3):

A lot depends on what the supplied ppd for the printer proposes. List the options, and their current settings shown by an asterisk next to that option. 
The options and values are entirely arbitrary, but fairly conventional so you might see eg:

```
$ lpoptions -l
PageSize/Media Size: Photo4x6tab A6 8x10 Legal Letter EnvDL ...
InputSlot/Media Source: *Auto Main
...
```

Look for an option that seems to specify the input or tray to use. If it has an `Auto` value that is not the current one (ie `*Auto`), then set it with eg

```
$ lpoptions -o InputSlot=Auto
```

or with sudo to change it for all users. You can probably do this with gui too at `http://localhost:631/` but it's harder.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced similar problem.
On Ubuntu12 everything worked fine with this command:

```
lp -o media=a4,Tray2 <FILE_TO_PRINT>
```

After I upgraded to Ubuntu16 that command to longer worked, but this one is:

```
lp -o media=A4 -o InputSlot=Tray2 <FILE_TO_PRINT>
```